# MediaPipe Pose Landmarks to BVH

Tags: animation, computer-vision, blender, mediapipe, fbx

I was trying to map/translate the MP Pose Landmarks (33 values) to a BVH hierarchy and my model keeps getting flipped and bent for some reasons. The challenges I came across,

1. For the motion, how to obtain Z, X, Y rotations from the MP landmarks coordinates?
2. For the Hip (root), how to update the position co-ordinates, X, Y, Z and for the rest, how to update the rotation values (Z, X, Y), with the incoming frames?

If anyone can help answering any of these or maybe even point towards the right resource, that would be amazing. Thanks in advance!

## **The hierarchy of the BVH file is:**

```
HIERARCHY
ROOT hip
{
  OFFSET 0 0 0
  CHANNELS 6 Xposition Yposition Zposition Zrotation Yrotation Xrotation
  JOINT abdomen
  {
    OFFSET 0 20.6881 -0.73152
    CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
    JOINT chest
    {
      OFFSET 0 11.7043 -0.48768
      CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
      JOINT neck
      {
        OFFSET 0 22.1894 -2.19456
        CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
        JOINT head
        {
          OFFSET -0.24384 7.07133 1.2192
          CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
          JOINT leftEye
          {
            OFFSET 4.14528 8.04674 8.04672
            CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
            End Site
            {
              OFFSET 1 0 0
            }
          }
          JOINT rightEye
          {
            OFFSET -3.6576 8.04674 8.04672
            CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
            End Site
            {
              OFFSET 1 0 0
            }
          }
        }
      }
      JOINT rCollar
      {
        OFFSET -2.68224 19.2634 -4.8768
        CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
        JOINT rShldr
        {
          OFFSET -8.77824 -1.95073 1.46304
          CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
          JOINT rForeArm
          {
            OFFSET -28.1742 -1.7115 0.48768
            CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
            JOINT rHand
            {
              OFFSET -22.5879 0.773209 7.07136
              CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
              JOINT rThumb1
              {
                OFFSET -1.2192 -0.487915 3.41376
                CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                JOINT rThumb2
                {
                  OFFSET -3.37035 -0.52449 3.41376
                  CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                  End Site
                  {
                    OFFSET -1.78271 -1.18214 1.43049
                  }
                }
              }
              JOINT rIndex1
              {
                OFFSET -7.75947 0.938293 5.60832
                CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                JOINT rIndex2
                {
                  OFFSET -2.54057 -0.884171 1.56538
                  CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                  End Site
                  {
                    OFFSET -1.62519 -0.234802 1.16502
                  }
                }
              }
              JOINT rMid1
              {
                OFFSET -8.24714 1.18213 3.41376
                CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                JOINT rMid2
                {
                  OFFSET -3.10165 -0.590103 1.0647
                  CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                  End Site
                  {
                    OFFSET -2.48547 -0.328903 0.83742
                  }
                }
              }
              JOINT rRing1
              {
                OFFSET -8.82822 0.546677 1.51678
                CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                JOINT rRing2
                {
                  OFFSET -2.60934 -0.819778 -0.0198488
                  CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                  End Site
                  {
                    OFFSET -2.33842 -0.294052 0.168128
                  }
                }
              }
              JOINT rPinky1
              {
                OFFSET -8.27202 -0.0477905 -0.4584
                CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                JOINT rPinky2
                {
                  OFFSET -1.82734 -0.647385 -0.700984
                  CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                  End Site
                  {
                    OFFSET -1.69225 -0.51767 -0.607171
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      JOINT lCollar
      {
        OFFSET 2.68224 19.2634 -4.8768
        CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
        JOINT lShldr
        {
          OFFSET 8.77824 -1.95073 1.46304
          CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
          JOINT lForeArm
          {
            OFFSET 28.1742 -1.7115 0.48768
            CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
            JOINT lHand
            {
              OFFSET 22.5879 0.773209 7.07136
              CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
              JOINT lThumb1
              {
                OFFSET 1.2192 -0.487915 3.41376
                CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                JOINT lThumb2
                {
                  OFFSET 3.37035 -0.52449 3.41376
                  CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                  End Site
                  {
                    OFFSET 1.78271 -1.18214 1.43049
                  }
                }
              }
              JOINT lIndex1
              {
                OFFSET 7.75947 0.938293 5.60832
                CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                JOINT lIndex2
                {
                  OFFSET 2.54057 -0.884171 1.56538
                  CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                  End Site
                  {
                    OFFSET 1.62519 -0.234802 1.16502
                  }
                }
              }
              JOINT lMid1
              {
                OFFSET 8.24714 1.18213 3.41376
                CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                JOINT lMid2
                {
                  OFFSET 3.10165 -0.590103 1.0647
                  CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                  End Site
                  {
                    OFFSET 2.48547 -0.328903 0.83742
                  }
                }
              }
              JOINT lRing1
              {
                OFFSET 8.82822 0.546677 1.51678
                CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                JOINT lRing2
                {
                  OFFSET 2.60934 -0.819778 -0.0198488
                  CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                  End Site
                  {
                    OFFSET 2.33842 -0.294052 0.168128
                  }
                }
              }
              JOINT lPinky1
              {
                OFFSET 8.27202 -0.0477905 -0.4584
                CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                JOINT lPinky2
                {
                  OFFSET 1.82734 -0.647385 -0.700984
                  CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
                  End Site
                  {
                    OFFSET 1.69225 -0.51767 -0.607171
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  JOINT rButtock
  {
    OFFSET -8.77824 4.35084 1.2192
    CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
    JOINT rThigh
    {
      OFFSET 0 -1.70687 -2.19456
      CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
      JOINT rShin
      {
        OFFSET 0 -36.8199 0.73152
        CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
        JOINT rFoot
        {
          OFFSET 0.73152 -45.1104 -5.12064
          CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
          End Site
          {
            OFFSET -1.1221 -3.69964 12.103
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  JOINT lButtock
  {
    OFFSET 8.77824 4.35084 1.2192
    CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
    JOINT lThigh
    {
      OFFSET 0 -1.70687 -2.19456
      CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
      JOINT lShin
      {
        OFFSET 0 -36.8199 0.73152
        CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
        JOINT lFoot
        {
          OFFSET -0.73152 -45.1104 -5.12064
          CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
          End Site
          {
            OFFSET 1.1221 -3.69964 12.103
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## **The function I have used for rotation:**

```
def rot(a, b):
    c = b - a
    c /= np.linalg.norm(c)
    
    thetaZ = np.arctan2(c[1], c[0])
    thetaX = np.arctan2(c[2], c[0]**2 + c[1]**2)
    thetaY = np.arctan2(c[2], np.sqrt(c[0]**2 + c[1]**2))
    
    thetaZdeg = float('{:.3f}'.format(np.rad2deg(thetaZ))[:-1])
    thetaXdeg = float('{:.3f}'.format(np.rad2deg(thetaX))[:-1])
    thetaYdeg = float('{:.3f}'.format(np.rad2deg(thetaY))[:-1])
    
    return [thetaZdeg, thetaXdeg, thetaYdeg]
```

## **The mapping that I have done from landmark to skeleton:**

```
def dataLoad2(i, j, res1, res2):
    return str((res1[i] + res2[j] / 2)[2]) + " " + str((res1[i] + res2[j] / 2)[1]) + " " + str((res1[i] + res2[j] / 2)[0]) + " "     

def dataLoad(i, res):
    try:
        return str(res[i][2]) + " " + str(res[i][1]) + " " + str(res[i][0]) + " "  
    except:
        return str(res[2]) + " " + str(res[1]) + " " + str(res[0]) + " "     

def writeBVH(res):
    hip = dataLoad2(24, 23, res, res)
    chest = dataLoad2(11, 12, res, res)

    temp = list(np.array([eval(i) for i in hip.split(' ')[:-1]]) + np.array([eval(i) for i in chest.split(' ')[:-1]]) / 2)
    abdomen = dataLoad(0, temp)
    mouth = dataLoad2(10, 9, res, res)

    temp = list(np.array([eval(i) for i in mouth.split(' ')[:-1]]) + np.array([eval(i) for i in chest.split(' ')[:-1]]) / 2)
    neck = dataLoad(0, temp)
    head = dataLoad(0, res)

    lefteye = dataLoad(2, res)
    righteye = dataLoad(5, res)

    rcollar = dataLoad2(12, 10, res, res)
    rshldr = dataLoad(12, res)
    rforearm = dataLoad(14, res)
    rhand = dataLoad(16,res)

    rthumb1 = dataLoad2(16, 22, res, res)
    rthumb2 = dataLoad(22, res)

    rindex1 = dataLoad2(16, 20, res, res)
    rindex2 = dataLoad(20, res)

    ''' Edit These After Using Hand Landmarks '''
    rmid1 = dataLoad2(16, 20, res, res)
    rmid2 = dataLoad(20, res)

    rring1 = dataLoad2(16, 20, res, res)
    rring2 = dataLoad(20, res)
    ''' Edit These After Using Hand Landmarks '''

    rpinky1 = dataLoad2(16, 18, res, res)
    rpinky2 = dataLoad(18, res)

    lcollar = dataLoad2(11, 9, res, res)
    lshldr = dataLoad(11, res)
    lforearm = dataLoad(13, res)
    lhand = dataLoad(15,res)

    lthumb1 = dataLoad2(15, 21, res, res)
    lthumb2 = dataLoad(21, res)

    lindex1 = dataLoad2(15, 19, res, res)
    lindex2 = dataLoad(19, res)

    ''' Edit These After Using Hand Landmarks '''
    lmid1 = dataLoad2(15, 19, res, res)
    lmid2 = dataLoad(19, res)

    lring1 = dataLoad2(15, 19, res, res)
    lring2 = dataLoad(19, res)
    ''' Edit These After Using Hand Landmarks '''

    lpinky1 = dataLoad2(15, 17, res, res)
    lpinky2 = dataLoad(17, res)

    rbuttock = dataLoad(24, res)
    rthigh = dataLoad2(24, 26, res, res)
    rshin = dataLoad(26, res)
    rfoot = dataLoad(28, res)

    lbuttock = dataLoad(23, res)
    lthigh = dataLoad2(23, 25, res, res)
    lshin = dataLoad(25, res)
    lfoot = dataLoad(27, res)

    return hip+hip+abdomen+chest+neck+head+lefteye+righteye+rcollar+rshldr+rforearm+rhand+rthumb1+rthumb2+rindex1+rindex2+rmid1+rmid2+rring1+rring2+rpinky1+rpinky2+lcollar+lshldr+lforearm+lhand+lthumb1+lthumb2+lindex1+lindex2+lmid1+lmid2+lring1+lring2+lpinky1+lpinky2+rbuttock+rthigh+rshin+rfoot+lbuttock+lthigh+lshin+lfoot+"\n"
```

## **The main loop of real-time capture:**

```
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_drawing_styles = mp.solutions.drawing_styles
mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose

# For static images:
IMAGE_FILES = []
BG_COLOR = (192, 192, 192) # gray
with mp_pose.Pose(
    static_image_mode=True,
    model_complexity=2,
    enable_segmentation=True,
    min_detection_confidence=0.5) as pose:
  for idx, file in enumerate(IMAGE_FILES):
    image = cv2.imread(file)
    image_height, image_width, _ = image.shape
    # Convert the BGR image to RGB before processing.
    results = pose.process(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

    if not results.pose_landmarks:
      continue
    print(
        f'Nose coordinates: ('
        f'{results.pose_landmarks.landmark[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.NOSE].x * image_width}, '
        f'{results.pose_landmarks.landmark[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.NOSE].y * image_height})'
    )

    annotated_image = image.copy()
    # Draw segmentation on the image.
    # To improve segmentation around boundaries, consider applying a joint
    # bilateral filter to "results.segmentation_mask" with "image".
    condition = np.stack((results.segmentation_mask,) * 3, axis=-1) > 0.1
    bg_image = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    bg_image[:] = BG_COLOR
    annotated_image = np.where(condition, annotated_image, bg_image)
    # Draw pose landmarks on the image.
    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
        annotated_image,
        results.pose_landmarks,
        mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
        landmark_drawing_spec=mp_drawing_styles.get_default_pose_landmarks_style())
    cv2.imwrite('/tmp/annotated_image' + str(idx) + '.png', annotated_image)
    # Plot pose world landmarks.
    mp_drawing.plot_landmarks(
        results.pose_world_landmarks, mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)

temp = [0.00] * 132
count = 0
with open("test.bvh", "a") as bvh:
    # For webcam input:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    with mp_pose.Pose(
        min_detection_confidence=0.5,
        min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as pose:
      while cap.isOpened():
        success, image = cap.read()
        if not success:
          print("Ignoring empty camera frame.")
          # If loading a video, use 'break' instead of 'continue'.
          continue

        # To improve performance, optionally mark the image as not writeable to
        # pass by reference.
        image.flags.writeable = False
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        results = pose.process(image)
        if results.pose_landmarks:
            count += 1
            res = np.array([[res.x, res.y, res.z] for res in results.pose_landmarks.landmark]) 
            t = writeBVH(res)
            t = t.split(' ')[:-1]
            res = [[float('{:.3f}'.format(float(t[0]))[:-1]), float('{:.3f}'.format(float(t[1]))[:-1]), float('{:.3f}'.format(float(t[2]))[:-1])]]
            t = np.array(list(map(float, t))).reshape(44,3) 
            temp = np.array(list(map(float, temp))).reshape(44,3)
            for i in range(1, 44):
                res.append(rot(t[i], temp[i]))
            res = list(np.array(res).flatten())
            (res[4], res[5]) = (res[5], res[4])
            s = ''
            for i in res:
                s += str(i) + ' '
            s += '\n'
            bvh.write(s)
            temp = list(temp.flatten())
        # Draw the pose annotation on the image.
        image.flags.writeable = True
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
            image,
            results.pose_landmarks,
            mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
            landmark_drawing_spec=mp_drawing_styles.get_default_pose_landmarks_style())
        # Flip the image horizontally for a selfie-view display.
        cv2.imshow('MediaPipe Pose', cv2.flip(image, 1))
        if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == 27:
          break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print(count)
```